# Why is a 95% width h1 not as wide as a 95% fixed div?

Tags: css

**Short Version**

Why is a 95% width `h1` not as wide as a 95% fixed div?

And what can I do to make the `h1` the same width (whilst maintaining the `fixed` property of the div)?

```css
#mobile_wrapper {
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 95%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#mobile_menu {
  background: aqua;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 60px;
}
#mobile_logo {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  text-align: center;
}
#mobile_logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#mobile_cart {
  width: 60px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
#mobile_cart li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
h1 {
  width: 95%;
  background: gold;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile_wrapper">
  <div id="mobile_menu">
    menu
  </div>
  <div id="mobile_logo">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-q-c-150-50-6.jpg">
  </div>
  <ul id="mobile_cart">
    <li>i</li>
    <li>i</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>
TITLE
</h1>
```

**jsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/mqqytqwe/

**Long Version**

I've been slowly working through a number of * learning opportunities * in the process of completing a fairly simple task - creating a fixed header area for mobile viewing.

To a fairly satisfying degree, I've learnt about:

- Floating:
  https://youtu.be/xara4Z1b18I
- Positioning (Static, Relative, Absolute, Fixed, Inherit):
  http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101
- Why inline-blocks have space between them:
  https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements
- Box-sizing:
  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts

Where padding and borders are included in the elements width, rather than added to it:

[image]
Image Source:  [teamtreehouse.com](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts)

And it's cool that I can view a lot of these things in the layout tab of Firebug:

[image]

But I haven't been able to apply my knowledge of these areas to understand:

Why is a 95% width `h1` not as wide as a 95% fixed div?

And what can I do to make the `h1` the same width (whilst maintaining the `fixed` property of the div)?

Comment: Remove the margin on the `body` https://jsfiddle.net/mqqytqwe/2/

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing.  (I was preparing myself for some super insight into `h1` properties).  Thanks.

Comment: Always good to use dev tools and hover over parent/child elements when you can't see anything on the element in question. Often you'll then see some padding or margin on something else that's causing the problem ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is positioned relatively to `html` and second to `body`. The fix is:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#mobile_wrapper {
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 95%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#mobile_menu {
  background: aqua;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 60px;
}
#mobile_logo {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  text-align: center;
}
#mobile_logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#mobile_cart {
  width: 60px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
#mobile_cart li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
h1 {
  width: 95%;
  background: gold;
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile_wrapper">
  <div id="mobile_menu">
    menu
  </div>
  <div id="mobile_logo">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-q-c-150-50-6.jpg">
  </div>
  <ul id="mobile_cart">
    <li>i</li>
    <li>i</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>
TITLE
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the body element.

```
body {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `mobile_wrapper` has `position: fixed`:

https://jsfiddle.net/az77u8c8/

You also haven't cleared your floats. There should be a block element with `clear: both`.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with using div vs h2 elements. It's because your div is using fixed positioning. % values for a `position: fixed` element are calculated as a % of the viewport (e.g. normally the browser width, but in your js fiddle the frame).

Your H1 tag is static position, so a percentage width based on the width of it's container, in this case the body. You might think that the body will be the same width as the viewport, but most browsers add some padding/margin to the body.

If you select the 'normalize css' option in jsfiddle, this probably gives the result you were expecting.

https://jsfiddle.net/4hnn3skv/

This uses [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to enforce consistent behaviour cross browser. It's usually a good idea to use this or a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Answer (score 0):

width:95%
It gives same result for h1 and div

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 
 
 .TT{
 width:95%;
 background-color:red;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="d1" class="TT">m</div>
  <h1 id="hh" class="TT">m</h1>
</body>
</html>
```